# TERADATA SQL: RANDOM SAMPLE AVOID BREAKING GROUPS

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata, sample

I have c. 13m records that look something like;

| Cust_ID | Order |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | a1 |
| 123 | a1 |
| 123 | a2 |
| 456 | a2 |
| 789 | b2 |
| 789 | b3 |

I want to take a sample of say 2m but want to avoid breaking up any cusotmer records (i.e if 123 is in the sample all three records need to be included).

I tried sample but this has the issue that customer 123 might only have 1 record when I need all three. I also tried using QUALIFY altering the following found on antoher question;

`SELECT *  FROM TABLE1  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CUST_ID  ORDER BY NULL) <= 50;`

However this 50 records within a group.

I'm kind of thinking I need a subquery but I'm drawing a blank. Any help

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly, but something like `select * from table1 where cust_id in (<set of sample cust_ids>)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably clearest to do in stages:

1. Make a list of Cust_IDs and corresponding row counts.
2. Randomize the list.
3. Use a cumulative sum to determine when we meet (or slightly exceed)
   the desired sample size.

.

```
SELECT t.* FROM Table1 t JOIN
    (SELECT Cust_ID FROM 
        (SELECT Cust_ID, cnt, RANDOM(-2147483648,2147483647) as rnd FROM
            (SELECT Cust_ID, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY 1) RowCountByID
        ) RandomizedList
    /* Cumulative sum not including current row */
    QUALIFY COALESCE(SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY rnd ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) < 2000000
    ) SampleIDs
  ON SampleIDs.Cust_ID = t.Cust_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need real randomness, but just want to pick some data as a sample and you are ready to play a little with this, there are simple options. You have about 23m rows of which you want around 2m. That's a fraction of 1/11.5 of the data.

The idea with `QUALIFY` would require `DENSE_RANK`, no partition and an `ORDER BY cust_id` or better some function invoked on cust_id, so as not to get only the low IDs or the high IDs. (For while IDs should be purely technical, lower IDs will probably mean long-term customers, and high IDs new customers, so getting only one of these groups would make a bad sample.)

```
select * 
from orders
qualify dense_rank () over (order by hashrow(cust_id)) <= 87;
```

You will have to adjust the result (87 here) to get about 2m rows. With 1000 customers and maybe about 1000 resulting hash codes, too, 87 would be about the portion you want.

Another simple option that I frequently use is a modulo operation. Divide the customer ID by 11 or 12, decide for whichever modulo result, and see how many rows you get:

```
select *
from orders
where cust_id mod 11 = 1;
```